# Cannot authenticate using spa

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-backpack, laravel-sanctum

I have my API that run on this url: `https://example.com`, and my vue.js app which runs on this: `https://app.example.com`. So I configured as the following the `.env`:

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=.example.com
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=https://app.example.com
```

the axios configuration contains the following:

import axios from 'axios'

```
const server = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://example.com'
})
server.defaults.withCredentials = true
server.defaults.withXSRFToken = true
```

within the file `sanctum.php` I setted as guard `api`:

```
'guard' => ['api']
```

and within `kernel.php` I did:

```
'api' => [
        \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class.':api',
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],
```

I also added:

```
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
```

within `$middleware` group.

The application flow is the following: when I press the login button I sent a request to:

```
/sanctum/csrf-cookie
```

which return 204 and set the cookie, then I perform the login request that return 204, so far everything seems good. At the end, I try to sent a GET request to `/user` that is protected as the following:

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/user', [UserController::class, 'index']);
});
```

but I get `unauthorized`. I spend the whole day try to figur out, tried a lot of solutions but no one has worked.

I get the same result on postman.

**UPDATE**

***config/sanctum.php***

```
<?php

use Laravel\Sanctum\Sanctum;

return [

    'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
        '%s%s',
        'localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1',
        Sanctum::currentApplicationUrlWithPort()
    ))),

    'guard' => ['web'],

    'expiration' => null,

    'token_prefix' => env('SANCTUM_TOKEN_PREFIX', ''),

    'middleware' => [
        'authenticate_session' => Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        'encrypt_cookies' => App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        'verify_csrf_token' => App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    ],

];
```

***config.cors.php***

```
<?php

return [
    
    'paths' => [
        'api/*',
        'login',
        'logout',
        'register',
        'sanctum/csrf-cookie'
    ],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,

];
```

***config/session.php***

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return [

    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),

    'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),

    'expire_on_close' => false,

    'encrypt' => false,

    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),

    'connection' => env('SESSION_CONNECTION'),

    'table' => 'sessions',

    'store' => env('SESSION_STORE'),

    'lottery' => [2, 100],

    'cookie' => env(
        'SESSION_COOKIE',
        Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session'
    ),

    'path' => '/',

    'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN'),

    'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE'),

    'http_only' => true,

    'same_site' => 'lax',

    'partitioned' => false,

];
```

***config/auth.php***

```
<?php

return [

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],


    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_reset_tokens',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],

    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

***.env***

```
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

SESSION_DOMAIN=.example.com
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=https://app.example.com
```

**Notice that both domains are https registered with letsencrypt, I just hided them for privacy reason.**

Comment: first there should be the request to ```/sanctum/csrf-cookie``` then the one to the actual login (with username/mail and psw) then you can call ```/user```. In dev tools you should see (at least i used to see) double request with codes 204 and 200/201 i dont remember which, but the real request are the ones that return 200/201

Comment: @suxgri yeah, is exactly what I did .. unfortunately I constantly get "unauthenticated" for some weird reason

Comment: also, i think guard should be 'web' in sanctum config

Comment: do you have a git repo of this if yes kindly provide the link thanks

Comment: can you add the config cors and the code for the login controller?

Comment: @sfarzoso are you using sanctum token or session for authentication. Normally, We use sanctum token for authentication purpose. If you using token then I think I know the problem. Just confirm me, then I think I can help you.

Comment: @M-Khawar I set `session` as driver, @suxgri I've updated the question with other config

Comment: ok, but the login controller is still missing, also to debug the issue you may hit (right after the login call) a route that does not require authentication to log the session and see if it has an auth entry (and you should also check that your login attempts have not created entries in the personal_access_token db table)

Comment: @suxgri you can find the `LoginController` on this link: https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/blob/main/src/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php
I'm using laravel backpack so the route look like this: `Route::post('/login', [LoginController::class, 'login'])->name('api.login');`. Also I've created a test route, and I added a function with the following content: `Route::get('/test', function() {
   $authInfo = auth()->user();
   dd($authInfo);
});`  I get null

Comment: i did suggest logging the session not the user as we know there is no user, something like ```Route::get('/test', function(Request $request) {  $request->session()->all();});``` and check if there is a line that contains the word auth (or authentication) followed by user id.. if not present (as i believe) that means that the login was not successful (and i believe you should see it in the dev tools)

Comment: @suxgri I added your code and I get: `_token" => "IHOGN9SOwvjqVtRfSIj6e96xQzum8rRuzmF4dkmdj`

Comment: ok so we know that the login part is not working because there is no authentication in the session. i believe you are probably using laravel backpack default authentication backend mixed with the sanctum frontend authentication, and clearly the two do not work together

Comment: also laravel-backpack does not seem to be a vue frontend app + laravel backend but a 'classic' laravel + blade templating engine app. i am not sure how you are planning to make it work.

Comment: @suxgri I would like to use backpack for backend operations only, then the vue.js app should interact with the api routes. Is there a way to make this working using csrf token?

Comment: check discussion you started with mohammad, i ll post there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256892/discussion-between-sfarzoso-and-suxgri).

Comment: @suxgri cold you please join to chat?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a `cookie not sticking` problem. To troubleshoot an SPA and API setup you will need to trace browser HTTP requests and look at request / response headers. Here are a couple of pointers:

**CORS**

When using cross origin cookies and returning the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header you cannot set allowed origins to `*`. You need to use an exact domain name:

```
'allowed_origins' => ['https://app.example.com']
```

**COOKIE SETTINGS**

Use these settings if you want to send the cookie in both API requests and static content requests, and so that you use cookies with the best security settings:

```
Domain: .example.com
SameSite: strict
```

**LOCAL PC SETUP**

Reproduce problems on your local computer by editing your `/etc/hosts` file and defining development domains:

```
127.0.0.1 example-dev.com app.example-dev.com
```

Then run your SPA using a URL such as `http://app example-dev.com:3000` and the API at a URL such as [http://example-dev.com:3001`](http://example-dev.com:3001%60).

The SPA and API must run in the same site as represented by these domain names. If this is not true the browser will consider cookies to be third-party and is likely to drop them.

Same site cookie logic can use different ports and must use the same scheme (http or https). Your setup is same site and cross origin.

**NEXT STEPS**

See if this configuration helps. If you still experience problems, update your question with HTTP request details:

- Pre-flight OPTIONS request and response headers
- The response headers that set the `set-cookie` header
- The request headers for the following request, which should contain a `cookie` header

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately these suggestions also didn't work. I managed to fix things by using a bearer token via an axios interceptor, anyway thanks again for the support

Answer (score 0):

I can feel your pain, I struggled with it at my time.
I'm using the same practice for my web app. I achieved it with the same steps.

I notice one difference in env. I use:

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=.get-set-sold.test
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=.get-set-sold.test
```

☝️ Use "." and remove `https://`

Comment: I followed your suggestion, so now I have: `.example.com` for `SESSION_DOMAIN` and `SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS`, but still I get `401` within vue and postman, I'm about to go crazy D:

Answer (score 0):

try hitting the following controller when logging in (i assumed you log in with email and password):

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;
use Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
  public function login()
  {
    request()->validate([
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email'],
        'password' => ['required'],
    ]);

    /**
     * We are authenticating a request from our frontend.
     */
    if (EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::fromFrontend(request())) {
        $this->authenticateFrontend();
    }
    /**
     * We are authenticating a request from a 3rd party.
     */
    else {
        // Use token authentication.
    }
    //here you could check that session contains authentication 'entry'
}

private function authenticateFrontend()
{
    if (! Auth::guard('web')
        ->attempt(
            request()->only('email', 'password'),
            request()->boolean('remember')
        )) {
        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'email' => __('auth.failed'),
        ]);
    }
}
}
```

Check the response in devtools also.

Comment: I tried the `laravel-ui` code for login controller, and I get always 401 unauthorized, seems that for some reason the session isn't stored across the requests.

Answer (score -1):

I think you missed setting the `supports_credentials` option to `true` in `config/cors.php`

Comment: I already have this too .. check my update please

Comment: Could you delete the 'https://' in the .env 'SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS' option and test it again

Comment: deleting ` https://` return this error: `CSRF token mismatch.`

Comment: could you try to update 'SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS' to 'example.com,.example.com' or 'example.com,app.example.com'

Comment: if I set `example.com,.example.com` the login return the cookie but the user request return 401

Comment: Please double check the logic at the index action of the UserController. you could test it by adding 'return response()->json(['status' => 'ok']);' at the begining  of that action

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256871/discussion-between-mohammad-al-ani-and-sfarzoso).